# Geometry tools for python

Tags: ros, python, geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to perform some basic geometry computations using python, for example calculating the euclidean distance between two points. Of course, implementing that is easy enough, but littering code with this kind of basic functions seems pretty redundant.

Searching for a existing solution I only found the [pr2_python](https://kforge.ros.org/Sushi/www/pr2_python/pr2_python.geometry_tools-module.html) package. This is basically exactly what I'm looking for, but it is not available as a package from .debs and very heavyweight in it's dependencies.

Any other options, or is everyone just copying and pasting as needed? :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45309/geometry-tools-for-python/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alternatives might be numpy/scipy and the `tf.transformations` library that you can find in `tf/src/tf/transformations.py`. PyKDL could work, too.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think a lot of people have their own file of python geometry functions - pr2_python is the result of merging a few of ours into one file. The functions use tf.transformations, and provide a little higher level, ros specific functionality, such as converting between transform messages and homogeneous matrices. If there's enough interest, maybe we could clean up that file and move it somewhere in the geometry stack.  Until then you can copy the files you need out of pr2_python (they should only depend on tf, numpy, and a couple other things)

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-10-08**:
There's a lot of stuff in pr2_python that I've found quite useful, though not always quite right. The heavyweight dependencies are an issue I've noticed too. If you wanted to move it over to github (and maybe split some of the pieces out), I'd be more than happy to help out.